# Throw statement in exception's method signature

Tags: c++, exception

What is the purpose of the throw statement in the following code?

```
struct MyException : public exception
{
  const char * what () const throw ()
  {
    return "C++ Exception";
  }
};
```

Comment: It's [Goodenough's legacy](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~bec/courses/csci5535-s09/reading/goodenough-exceptions.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tells the compiler (and the reader) that this function will
never exit via an exception.  More importantly, in this case, it
tells the compiler and the reader that all overloads of this
function must fulfill the same condition.  (In this case, it is
probably present because the function `what` is declared this
way in `std::exception`.)

EDIT:

This is called an exception specification, and since C++11,
comes in two forms: `throw()` and `noexcept`.  And the form
`throw()` also allows specifying type names in the parentheses,
in which case, you guarantee not to throw anything incompatible
with those types.  (In the C++11 grammar, the `throw()` form
is referred to as a dynamic exception specification.)

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that it's called a *(dynamic) exception specification*.

Comment: Done, and I mention `noexcept` as well.